# What's this regulatory symbol?

Tags: symbol, certification

I am trying to identify this symbol as a part of personal research. I could not find any leads with Google Image search.

[image]

Comment: A context would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the symbol used by the Ukrainian State Committee for Technical Regulation and Consumer Policy.

I'd give you a URL but the links from their [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Committee_for_Technical_Regulation_and_Consumer_Policy) don't seem to be working!